# What's the best way to automatically test an AngularJS application served by Spring?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven

I have an AngularJS application served through Spring. My Spring application gets tested when being built through maven, I'm not sure how to include automatic tests for angular though.

Comment: the [official Angularjs tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) develops an app with jasmine and protractor automated tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can do unit testing even for Angular JS, with for example: Jasmine and Karma (you can add this to your maven build too)
- For GUI based End-To-End test, I recommend to use [Selenium 2 (WebDriver)](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is another option for GUI based End-To-End test. Protractor E2E test is a framework for AngularJS apps, it interacts with it via Selenium (WebDriver).

http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup